# Do $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices and they are both invertible. Can we say that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A more general result:

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, then we have for a scalar $\lambda \ne 0$:

$ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ iff $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ .

Proof: if $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ , then there is $x \ne 0$ such that

$(*)$  $ABx= \lambda x$.

Let $y:=Bx$. Then $y \ne 0$  (otherwise we would get from $(*)$ that $ \lambda =0$ or $x=0$).

Now we have

$$ BAy=BABx=B(ABx)=B( \lambda x)=\lambda Bx = \lambda y.$$

It follows that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$.

Comment: If $A, B$ are square and $AB$ is invertible then $A$ and $B$ are both invertible, so you can remove the $\lambda \neq 0$ assumption. $0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$. (Equivalently, $AB$ is invertible if and only if $BA$ is invertible.)

Comment: The proof should consider the case for $AB$,$BA$ having all eigenvalues zero.

Comment: More generally, the above result holds true even when $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are rectangular, as long as $\mathbf{AB}$ and $\mathbf{BA}$ are square matrices (possibly of different orders!).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is correct. They have the same characteristic polynomial.
Look [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices).

Comment: could you prove that with using diagonalization of matrices? I tried to write down these matrices as a product of a matrix with eigenvectors and a digonal matrix with eigenvalues but couldn't prove that.

Comment: Who says that the matrices are diagonalizable?

Comment: no one:) Thank you for your answer!:)

Comment: Since the asker says $A$ is invertible, we can just use the equation $$BA = A^{-1} (AB) A$$ of your reference which shows that $AB$ and $BA$ are similar (conjugated to each other) and hence have the same eigenvalues.