# If the eigenvalues of matrix AB are eigenvalues of matrix BA, does that mean they have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

From this question: [Do $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029376/do-ab-and-ba-have-the-same-eigenvalues/2029856#2029856), I am confused about this solution.

Why is it sufficient to show that every eigenvalue of AB is an eigenvalue of BA? That doesn't seem to prove the case that the eigenvalues of BA are eigenvalues of AB. Why don't you then need to show the other direction?

**Also, is this true for the general case of matrices not composed of AB, for all matrices $C,D \in R^{nxn}$?**

> A more general result:
>
> If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, then we have for a scalar
>   $\lambda \ne 0$:
>
> $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ iff $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of
>   $BA$ .
>
> Proof: if $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ , then there is $x \ne
> > 0$ such that
>
> $(*)$  $ABx= \lambda x$.
>
> Let $y:=Bx$. Then $y \ne 0$  (otherwise we would get from $(*)$ that $
> > \lambda =0$ or $x=0$).
>
> Now we have
>
> $$ BAy=BABx=B(ABx)=B( \lambda x)=\lambda Bx = \lambda y.$$
>
> It follows that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$.

Comment: What other eigenvalues might $BA$ have that $AB$ doesn’t?

Comment: @amd I don't know, but how are we sure that it doesn't?

Comment: What do you mean by “the general case?”

Comment: @amd all matrices $A \in R^{nxn}$, not just those composed of AB

Comment: So, your general-case question is “Are all of the eigenvalues of $A$ the same as those of $A$?!”

Comment: @amd My question was if A's eigenvalues are a subset of the eigenvalues of B's, then are their eigenvalues equivalent?

Comment: @amd I think I figured out that the answer is yes because their algebraic multiplicities add up to rank(A), so B cannot have more eigenvalues. Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $I$ are a subset of the eigenvalues of $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}}$. You didn’t say anything about multiplicity in the question. This “generalization” should really go into a separate question.

Comment: @amd I see, so we can't say that if the eigenvalues of A are eigenvalues of B that means the two matrices have the same eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

Now it is proved that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ then it is an eigenvalue of $BA$.

We can apply this result but replacing $A$ by $B$ and $B$ by $A$. That is.

"If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ then it is an eigenvalue of $AB$."

So, the proof is complete.

Comment: I should've realized that! But is this also true for the general case?

Answer (score 2):

It is by symmetry:

we write it out explicitly by switchign the roles of $A$ and $B$.

> Proof: if $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ , then there is $x \ne
> > 0$ such that
>
> $(*)$  $BAx= \lambda x$.
>
> Let $y:=Ax$. Then $y \ne 0$  (otherwise we would get from $(*)$ that $
> > \lambda =0$ or $x=0$).
>
> Now we have
>
> $$ ABy=ABAx=A(BAx)=A( \lambda x)=\lambda Ax = \lambda y.$$
>
> It follows that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$.

Comment: ah yes but what about for the general case?

Comment: @Goldname What is your general case? Matricies AB and BA have the same characteristic polynomials? Its also true.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover matricies $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomials. Basic field $F$ assumed  is assumed to be arbitrary

1) If one of the matricies, say $A$ is invertible then $BA=A^{-1}(AB)A$ and we are done

2) None of $A$ or $B$ is invertible. Consider transcendental expansion $F(\varepsilon)$ - that is simply the field of all rational functions $\frac{P(\varepsilon)}{Q(\varepsilon)}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polinomials under $F$.
Consider $A_\varepsilon=A-\varepsilon I$ it is invertible as $\varepsilon$ isn't alghebraic number. So $|A_\varepsilon B-\lambda I|= |BA_\varepsilon -\lambda I|$ from which we have  $|AB-\lambda I-\varepsilon B|=|BA-\lambda I-\varepsilon B|$
Consider both sides of equality as polinomials with variable $\varepsilon$ (and fixing $\lambda$ wrom algebraic closure  of $F$), they are equal iff all the coefficients are equal, in particular free terms must be equal but free terms are  $|AB-\lambda I|$ and $|BA-\lambda I|.$

PS. If basic field $F$ is assumed real or complex the part 2) can be simplified. 
We can choose $\varepsilon>0$ sufficently small to have no nonzero eigenvalue of $A$ in $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ and getting equality $|AB-\lambda I-\varepsilon B|=|BA-\lambda I-\varepsilon B|$ send $\varepsilon$ to $0.$