# Comparison of rank and eigenvalues of matrix AB and BA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was unable to solve this question of linear algebra and hence I am posting it here.

> Let A and B be  n$\times $ n matrices over $\mathbb{C}$.Then which of the following are true:

A  AB and BA have same set of Eigenvalues.

B If AB and BA have same set of eigenvalues then BA= AB.

C If $A^{-1}$ exists then AB and BA  are similar

D The rank of AB is always equal as rank of BA.

I have done (C) .  Tried some matrices for D, but couldn't contradict it.  Fr A,B I don't have any idea so, your help is required.

Please guide me!

Comment: What does it mean for the rank of a matrix to be similar to the rank of another?

Comment: @nhmwhhxx It was equal ,sorry!

Comment: I think the main tool that you're supposed to use here is the characteristic polynomial. For example, your first question follows from the fact that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same polynomial and hence the same roots (eigenvalues). Moreover, your second question is probably false due to the same reason, just havce to think of a 2x2 example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### $AB$ and $BA$ have same set of Eigenvalues

True.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2029856/133152)

#### If $AB$ and $BA$ have same set of eigenvalues then $BA$=$AB$.

False.

From (A), the if part in (B) is trivially true for any two matrices. So you just need to pick any two non-commuting matrices as counter-[example](https://thejuniverse.org/PUBLIC/LinearAlgebra/LOLA/matCalc/noCanc.png). [Google Image](https://www.google.com/search?q=examples+of+commutative+matrix) has a good number of those. (But funny you have to search examples of commutative matrices.)

#### The rank of $AB$ is always equal as rank of $BA$.

False.

The easiest way to spot why this is false is to consider matrices as linear operators. If $A$ has non-trivial nullspace, and $B$ happens to map into that, yet A still maps out of the nullspace of $B$...

For example, consider

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In $\mathbb{R}^3, A$ only keeps 1st coordinate and throws it to 3rd. $B$ keeps 2nd & 3rd coordinate. Going through $A$ first and then $B$, you will end with 1st coordinate on 3rd slot. In other words, rank 1. Going through $B$ first and then $A$, since you lose 1st coordinate right away, you end with zero. In other words, rank 0.

Comment: How do you get from $\det(AB) = (\det A)(\det B)$ to the fact that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomials? There is more to be shown there.

Comment: @Joppy: I may just delete the determinant part and keep the link. I'll give it some thought. As for your second statement, it is not true. You may be missing multiplicity somewhere.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I was thinking only about diagonalisable matrices.